# Easiest way to be asynchronous (use await) in Startup.cs? web api app

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I would like an easy way to be async from the start of my web api application (Program.cs and Startup.cs)

Is this just a bad way to do things?  I can't find an easy way.
I would like to be async all the way, is this not easilsy possible?

In other words, I would like to use "await" in the Startup.cs file.

Startup.cs is part of the default template, so I'm not used to replacing it, but maybe there is another way to do things the "async" way.

The main need here is so I can call into KeyVault (GetSecretAsync) during my Startup.cs logic and avoid deadlocking thread issues.

Comment: 1. .NetCore does not have dead locking issues with Async there is no SynchronizationContext
2.  Why do you think you need async in your startup.  Majority of the methods call are CPU intensive so you will not gain any benefit.  The majority of the places you need Async like the configuration options will provide an async Method for you

Comment: so i'm trying to use KeyVault async calls in the Startup.cs, that's the main reason.  it seems like the best practice would just to be force sync for these calls if i need them in Startup.cs ??  and use await / async everywhere else?  does that sounds like 'best practice'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear what you mean, but ASP.NET Core is inherently asynchronous (it creates a thread-pool with multiple threads by default.) If you're wanting your individual API methods to be asynchronous you simply need to code them that way. The MVC ControllerBase class supports asynchronous action methods, so all you need to do is return a `Task<IActionResult>` instead of an `IActionResult` from your action methods. There is nothing to change within Program.cs or Startup.cs to enable that functionality.

There is also no way to force all action methods to be asynchronous, nor would that be a good idea. Actions which inherently will be performed on a single thread (and have no long IO waits) are better off blocking that thread until they return, otherwise you would end up with a lot of very expensive context switching with no benefit.

If you are looking to do something within the Program or Startup classes that you want to parallelize, then you would do so using the Task and/or Threading libraries and block until all of your parallel tasks complete. It would be highly unusual to need to do that much work on startup, however, and suggests that some rethinking of your design may be in order.

Finally, if you're looking to create background tasks that run continuously, then the only mechanism within ASP.NET Core for that is the [HostedService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services). But depending on what you are trying to accomplish, it is possible ASP.NET Core is simply the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: i cannot use await in Program.cs or Startup.cs

Comment: should i use .wait() in these files?  Or is there a way to use await?  thanks for the answer

Comment: What are you putting in Program.cs or Startup.cs that would be parallelized? They are startup/initialization classes.

Comment: the main issue is we need values from KeyVault and the KeyVault call (GetSecretAsync) is async

Comment: Ah. In that case, just block (`.Wait()` is fine) until the call returns. Make sure you are storing those values in memory and not attempting to retrieve them on every request, etc.

Comment: because of that I was hoping I could make them async?  but maybe that is bad practice.  at this point in time, there isn't a real way to refactor the keyvault logic, i just have to figure out how to make that stuff async, or use a .wait() somewhere

Comment: ok thanks!!  so just to make sure I understand, .wait is always frowned upon for the KeyVault call (GetSecretAsync) but really at some point I will have to use .Wait in the Startup.cs file?  And that is "best practice" no risk of deadlocking or thread issues?

Comment: i'm seeing "rumors" of making those calls async but haven't seen anything i really like

Comment: Your Program.Main function is only called once when the process starts up. MVC hasn't even started yet so there are no threads to deadlock. Concerns about blocking on calls to KeyVault access relate to runtime, not startup time.

Comment: @Hemp There is no SynchronizationContext in .Net Core Theads will not deadlock either way

Comment: @johnny5 In this case there is no "either way". He's talking about startup code where there is only one thread, a deadlock is inherently impossible. That's what I was trying to make clear.

Comment: @hemp, Yes, There is no "either way"  because Deadlocks related to await are not possible in .NET-Core because there is No SyncronizationContext.  Its misleading to inform the OP Otherwise because it infers that a deadlock could occur

Comment: I take your point. You are correct, wrt ASP.NET Core, *this type of* deadlock is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is in your `csproj` file, set the `LangVersion` to `7.1`. You could also use `Latest` if you'd rather.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <LangVersion>7.1</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then you make your Main method async

```
static async Task Main(string[] args) {
  //some async code goes here
}
```

Comment: This is an option. Typically should not be necessary, but if there's a lot of awaiting to be done in the startup code then I could see using it.

Comment: thanks!  I actually was playing around with this, but couldn't figure out how to get Startup.cs to be async?  any ideas on that?  or maybe something I could be using other than Startup.cs

Comment: @JBoothUA I'll look into it some more and get back to you, I feel like I might be close to something, but not quite yet. It mostly depends on where you need the async code. Assuming in ConfigureServices?

Comment: Startup is just a class of your creation. The built-in UseStartup code will inspect your startup class, look for two methods within the type you provide, instantiate (one instance of) your class, and call those methods if present. Those methods (ConfigureServices and Configure) presently can only be called synchronously.

You are certainly free to write your own startup logic rather than using .UseStartup().

Comment: The current IStartup definition is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.istartup

Comment: @nick correct.  we are using KeyVault values in ConfigureServices.  Thanks!

Comment: @JBoothUA if you really want to use await for accessing KeyVault, you could make your Main function async, access the KeyVault there, add the value to your DI container, then use DI resolved IStartup instead of convention-based startup. But that's a lot of hoops to jump for no real benefit since you can safely block on the KeyVault access instead.